# Mysql infile Data load

Tags: mysql, file-io

I am loading the data from different remote client.

ClientA load to tableA
ClientB load to tableB.

TableA and TableB have the similar schema. If it happened the loading at the same time, I would find the data for tableA in tableB.

The same user is being used for data loading.

Comment: So Where is this file coing from? A main MySQL server, I suppose.

Comment: No, the file is from remote Client machine